# How to configure AppDelegare.m in a react native project

Tags: react-native

I want to a configuration to the AppDelegate.m file use the 24hours format for the react-native-modal-datetime-picker. The documentation say do as the following

`The is24Hour prop is only available on Android but you use a small hack for enabling it on iOS by setting the app's default timezone as en_GB. To do so, edit your AppDelegate.m file, and add [[UIDatePicker appearance] setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]]; to application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

But i have no idea where i should add the flowing code in the AppDleate.m file

Where should i add the above code

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the quoted text, you should add it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIDatePicker appearance] setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];
}
```

Add the above code in `AppDelegate.m` file. This is where the launch process is completed and you should do such configurations here.